# DataStore with Objectify - Load entities/keys without specifying parent

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Within a transaction, I need to load several entities ( tenths-hundreds ) and those entities were assigned to one parent entity, so they are considered as one entity group ( otherwise we can't load those entities in a single transaction ), which works good, however every time we need to query those entities the parent entity gets loaded

`ofy().load().type(clazz).parent(parent).ids(keys);`

If we want to load the entities without the parent entity gets loaded then this expected to work and load the entities, but it doesn't

`ofy().load().type(clazz).ids(keys);`

The reason behind this, if two or more threads do call to load same/different entries ( but same parent ) it would cause too much load on the parent entity " java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: too much contention on these datastore entities. please try again."

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

The reason for which your `ofy().load().type(clazz).ids(keys)` doesn't *appear* to work is that you don't specify the parent key - which is equivalent to looking for keys of **root** entities (i.e. entities **without a parent**), which obviously yields a different result.

The parent key (actually the entire ancestry) is embeeded in a child entity key, see [Ancestor paths](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Python_Ancestor_paths).

So unfortunately you **have to** specify the parent - the "load" on the parent (actually on the entire entity group, especially at write operations) is the price to pay for the advantages of working within the same entity group.

Comment: This means loading X entity **keys** yield to loading X parent **entity** , which means within a transaction, you simply can't load 1K **keys** which completely doesn't make sense, and I'm not sure it's right..

Comment: Loading an entity or its key doesn't mean the parent entity or its key is also loaded (the parent might not even exist, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37283449/4495081).

Comment: The contention is caused by accessing the same entity group, not by the number of group entities/keys themselves.

Comment: Right, let me rewrite my issue.. if we load X entity, then the parent gets loaded X times, and assume there is just one more thread that is accessing _different_ entities but same parent, then this cause too many accesses to the same entity - **parent**.

Answer (score 0):

At the root of this question is a fundamental misunderstanding of how transactions and entity groups work in the datastore.

The official documentation is quite accessible:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions#Java_Entity_groups

I wrote this up some time ago, it may be easier to understand:

https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Concepts

Keep in mind that this isn't about loading the parent entity. It's about enlisting Entity Groups in a transaction. If you touch any entity in that EG (that is, any entity with a common parent key), you have enlisted the whole EG in the transaction.

Comment: So, the question is again, if we load X entity, then the parent gets loaded X times, and assume there is just one more thread that is accessing different entities but same parent, then this cause too many accesses to the same entity - parent ( exception occur ), how to better handle this ?

Comment: You need to carefully balance your needs for strong consistency on one hand and transaction throughput on the other. The right answer is almost always to live without strong consistency put your entities in separate entity groups, but it really depends on your application.

Comment: From [https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Concepts#entity-groups](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Concepts#entity-groups) "For that matter, you can create child entites with a parent Key (or any other key as a member field) that points to a nonexistant entity! Parent is only important in that it defines entity groups; if you do not need transactions across several entities, you may wish to use a normal nonparent key relationship - even if the entities have a conceptual parent-child relationship."
Would that help in my case ?